# Delete a Container with an Anchor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm creating a Wiki of my repositories on GitHub.

So, I want to remove that item from my list when I click "Remover" and open the repository on a new page when I click "Ver repositório".

But there's is my problem!

When I click the red anchor, it does remove, like I expected. Also, when I click the blue Anchor, it open the repository page and ALSO removes the list. What should I do?

This is the function that I created to remove the repository:

```
const handleRemoveRepo = (id) => {
    const remove = repos.filter((repo) => repo.id !== repo.id);
    setRepos(remove);
    if ((repo) => repo.id === repo.id) {
      return null;
    }
```

And this is the container to map everything:

```
    <Container>
      {repos.map(repo => <ItemRepo handleRemoveRepo={handleRemoveRepo} repo={repo} />)}  
    </Container>
```

My container comes from this index.js:

```
    <ItemContainer onClick={handleRemove}>
        <h3>{repo.name}</h3>
        <p>{repo.full_name}</p>
        <a href={repo.html_url} target="_blank">Ver repositório</a> <br />
        <a href="#" className="remove">Remover</a>
        <hr />
    </ItemContainer>
```

Thanks in advance.

[React App page for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdzcj.png)

I tried switching the conditional on my function, exporting a new function on ItemRepo, but both didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The "remove" click handler is assigned to the container, so it will be invoked if you click anywhere in the container:

```
<ItemContainer onClick={handleRemove}>
```

If it should only be invoked when clicking a specific link, assign the click hander to that specific link instead:

```
<a href="#" className="remove" onClick={handleRemove}>Remover</a>
```

---

As an aside... This shouldn't be a link.  It's not navigating the user anywhere, but is just performing an action in code.  A `<button>` is a more semantically appropriate element for that.  Which can be styled to not have the defaul button background, or styled however you want.

Comment: Jesus Christ! Can't believe I didnt test that out.

Sorry about that stupid question, tbh, I actually feel bad now. But thank you so much!

React is fun and I certainly will learn more about it.